# The name of the "Chinese Language" site

Tags: discussion, site-name

Why is the site named "[Chinese Language](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/)" when citizens of China speak non-mutually intelligible languages?

Counter-example, there are no sites dealing with "African Language" or "European Language".

Comment: @gboffi Feel free to start a discussion in https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/ if you want the site to be renamed.

Comment: @gboffi maybe take your concerns to Wikipedia, as well, then. Their article [Chinese language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_language) does also refer to a the group as a whole. And mentions "*The spoken varieties of Chinese are usually considered by native speakers to be variants of a single language. However, their lack of mutual intelligibility means they are sometimes considered separate languages in a family.*" - if you have strong evidence that they are *not* the same group, feel free to edit the article and cite your sources. Most people I know refer to the group as "chinese".

Comment: @gboffi I don't think users of Meta Stack Exchange can answer why the site has been named that way. You should perhaps ask that in https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/ or ask people in https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=chinese.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Closers: Based on [how this is tagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-name/info), and the question itself, I don't see this as relating to one site only (there ***is*** a couple of sites where the question could be asked, and perhaps one in particular); but there's no reason this question can't (or shouldn't) be asked on MSE - This is clear from the banner above.

Comment: @Rob Maybe this question could be relevant to other language sites, but the question seems to focus only on Chinese Language. Also, I think it is appropriate for the per-site metas to discuss why their language site name is named in a particular way as each language site might have its unique reason. So, I don't think it's appropriate to give a generic answer in Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Rob is correct. I'll copy the [tag:site-name] excerpt: *Questions about the naming of Stack Exchange sites, how specific sites were named, or questions that arise from a site being renamed*. If those were off topic here, the tag would not exist.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at [their tags page](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/tags), it seems questions about all sorts of different languages (e.g. Mandarin or Cantonese) are on-topic on the site.

Since all these different 'languages' are on-topic there, and it's common to refer to the whole group as Chinese Language, see also for example the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_language) on that topic, that's probably why the name "Chinese Language" was picked for the [Area 51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6388?phase=definition) and never changed.

Just like how, for example, on German Language, there are [tags](https://german.stackexchange.com/tags) for standard German, but also for Austrian or Bavarian: they are all grouped under "German Language".

Comment: I have to say that Bavarian and Hochdeutsch are mutually intelligible, so that piece of your argument is a bit of a stretch, but that excepted I feel that you're right and on point. Thank you.

Comment: Some dialects are very far apart. [Schwäbisch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swabian_German) is easy to understand, but [Swiss German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_German) and some [from the Rhineland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhenish_Franconian_languages) aren't (having had years of exposure).

Answer (score 14):

While I'm not Chinese speaking - I live in a majority Chinese speaking country, which is not China. Chinese isn't just referring to a nationality, and culturally, while they have singular roots, the various countries that speak Chinese and its dialects are culturally and politically not quite alike.

While Mandarin is the 'standard' variety of Chinese - across mainland China, Taiwan/ROC and Singapore, the other spoken and written variations are *dialects* as opposed to considered different languages. Cantonese, Hakka and other dialects, and even mainstream Mandarin are *never* referred to as separate languages, only different regional dialects of Chinese.

As such for practical purposes, and well, technical correctness, it's not incorrect to refer to the Chinese language and its dialects.

Comment: Same thing even applies in the English language: there are the Caribbean English-based creole languages, along with the Scots language.

Comment: Scots is different from english, though I'm a little more familiar with the Doric dialect which is nothing like english

Answer (score 8):

I'm a mod over at Chinese.SE.  This has been brought up on the meta there:

- [Why is the main site entitled "Chinese Language" rather than "Chinese Languages"?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/8099)
- [What languages count as Chinese?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1880/8099)

There's a clear consensus that anything that can be considered "Chinese" (in the sense of language) is on-topic at Chinese.SE, and we get occasional questions about all sorts of historical branches.  Questions are not restricted by time nor geography.

The thing is, the word "language" functions as both [a countable and uncountable noun](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/language), so "Chinese language" can be interpreted as "language which is considered Chinese", which is precisely what's on-topic.  So I feel it's not unreasonable as is.  It's not "*the* Chinese language" or "*a* Chinese language", it's just "Chinese language".

Perhaps the technically precise site name might be "Sinitic topolects", which I'm guessing few people would understand has anything to do with Chinese.

(By the way, when promoting the site on e.g. Reddit, I feel like it's easier to say "the Chinese Language Stack Exchange", and it would be more awkward to say "the Chinese Languages Stack Exchange".)

By the way, it's not the only site with this issue, e.g. [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) covers multiple sciences.  [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) covers chess variants without it being mentioned in the site's name.  And some sites, like [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) don't directly state what they're about in their title.  Sometimes we're flexible with site names.

But feel free to bring this up at [the site's meta](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/); it'd be easier to discuss with a concrete alternative name.

Comment: Actually - would you prefer it on your site? I could migrate it if so

Comment: The voting at meta.SE vs. the voting at the Chinese.SE meta is very different.  I'm worried such heavy voting may be misinterpreted down the line.

Comment: Its fine then, we'll keep it here

Comment: (It seems you commented so quickly on this answer that my edit within the 5-minute window [registered as an edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tmZx.png).  Curious.)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones SE implemented that change to fight abusing of the grace period, few years ago. Comment would "stop the timer" for the grace period, i.e. after a comment, edit would create new revision anyway.

Comment: "... the word "language" functions as both a countable and uncountable noun ..." - All our sites with the word "language" use the singular form, except for https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com (and possibly https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com, if that's not a stretch). The Cambridge site offers a [countable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/nouns-countable-and-uncountable) page, instead of the one at Collins, which offers this for "linguistic": https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/linguistic - so, indeed, we may not be consistent in our naming.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I'm curious to know how you found this question, if you don't mind.

Comment: @RandomPerson please note that Rebecca J. Stones has 16 K in rep, this suggests they are a frequent visitor to Meta, after all the question was posted only two days ago.  It could also be that someone pinged them.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні I pinged her in chat... so I was curious to know if they saw my message and found this post... https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61992217#61992217

Comment: Oh, I didn't get the ping in chat.  I was just browsing on my phone.

Answer (score -3):

> Why is the site named "Chinese Language"?

Because as you can read in the site's [Tour page](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Chinese Language and Usage is a question and answer site for experts, language enthusiasts, and people who have an interest in the Chinese language.

Or, to be even more clear, because the site is about, well, Chinese Language. Calling it by other name would be pretty confusing.

Comment: In which way calling the site "Chinese Languages" would be pretty confusing?

Comment: @gboffi for one, all other language sites on SE use singular language name. But that's a valid request, you can start new feature request in their per-site meta asking to change name of the site.

Comment: @gboffi After some searching, I found a question (from 2014) on the site's meta about exactly that (though both answers have been downvoted below 0): [Why is the main site entitled "Chinese Language" rather than "Chinese Languages"?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/29100) See these FAQs on their meta: [What languages count as Chinese?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1880/29100), [Are questions on specific topolects on topic?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1517/29100)

Comment: And finally, this Q&A on their main (i.e. non-meta) site is also relevant: [What does the term "Chinese" mean?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/9831/29100)

Comment: Huh.  It looks like that paragraph needs polishing.  "Chinese Language and Usage" is the old name for the site---it hasn't been used for years.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones can mods do it?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones: A link to your subsequent Chinese Language Meta post: [How should we polish the first paragraph of the tour page?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1952/29100)